# PyTorch - parameters not changing

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, pytorch

In an effort to learn how pytorch works, I am trying to do maximum likelihood estimation of some of the parameters in a multivariate normal distribution. However it does not seem to work for any of the covariance related parameters.

So my question is: why does this code not work?

```
import torch


def make_covariance_matrix(sigma, rho):
    return torch.tensor([[sigma[0]**2, rho * torch.prod(sigma)],
                         [rho * torch.prod(sigma), sigma[1]**2]])


mu_true = torch.randn(2)
rho_true = torch.rand(1)
sigma_true = torch.exp(torch.rand(2))

cov_true = make_covariance_matrix(sigma_true, rho_true)
dist_true = torch.distributions.MultivariateNormal(mu_true, cov_true)

samples = dist_true.sample((1_000,))

mu = torch.zeros(2, requires_grad=True)
log_sigma = torch.zeros(2, requires_grad=True)
atanh_rho = torch.zeros(1, requires_grad=True)

lbfgs = torch.optim.LBFGS([mu, log_sigma, atanh_rho])


def closure():
    lbfgs.zero_grad()
    sigma = torch.exp(log_sigma)
    rho = torch.tanh(atanh_rho)
    cov = make_covariance_matrix(sigma, rho)
    dist = torch.distributions.MultivariateNormal(mu, cov)
    loss = -torch.mean(dist.log_prob(samples))
    loss.backward()
    return loss


lbfgs.step(closure)

print("mu: {}, mu_hat: {}".format(mu_true, mu))
print("sigma: {}, sigma_hat: {}".format(sigma_true, torch.exp(log_sigma)))
print("rho: {}, rho_hat: {}".format(rho_true, torch.tanh(atanh_rho)))
```

output:

```
mu: tensor([0.4168, 0.1580]), mu_hat: tensor([0.4127, 0.1454], requires_grad=True)
sigma: tensor([1.1917, 1.7290]), sigma_hat: tensor([1., 1.], grad_fn=<ExpBackward>)
rho: tensor([0.3589]), rho_hat: tensor([0.], grad_fn=<TanhBackward>)

>>> torch.__version__
'1.0.0.dev20181127'
```

In other words, why have the estimates of `log_sigma` and `atanh_rho` not moved from their initial value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you create your covariance matrix is not *backprob-able*:

```
def make_covariance_matrix(sigma, rho):
    return torch.tensor([[sigma[0]**2, rho * torch.prod(sigma)],
                         [rho * torch.prod(sigma), sigma[1]**2]])
```

When creating a new tensor from (multiple) tensors, only the values of your input tensors will be kept. All additional information from the input tensors is stripped away, thus all *graph-connection* to your parameters is cut from this point, therefore backpropagation cannot get through.

**Here is a short example to illustrate this:**

```
import torch

param1 = torch.rand(1, requires_grad=True)
param2 = torch.rand(1, requires_grad=True)
tensor_from_params = torch.tensor([param1, param2])

print('Original parameter 1:')
print(param1, param1.requires_grad)
print('Original parameter 2:')
print(param2, param2.requires_grad)
print('New tensor form params:')
print(tensor_from_params, tensor_from_params.requires_grad)
```

*Output:*

```
Original parameter 1:
tensor([ 0.8913]) True
Original parameter 2:
tensor([ 0.4785]) True
New tensor form params:
tensor([ 0.8913,  0.4785]) False
```

As you can see the tensor, created from the parameters `param1` and `param2`, does not keep track of the gradients of `param1` and `param2`.

**So instead you can use this code that keeps the *graph connection* and is *backprob-able*:**

```
def make_covariance_matrix(sigma, rho):
    conv = torch.cat([(sigma[0]**2).view(-1), rho * torch.prod(sigma), rho * torch.prod(sigma), (sigma[1]**2).view(-1)])
    return conv.view(2, 2)
```

The values are concatenated to a flat tensor using `torch.cat`. Then they are brought into right shape using `view()`. 
This results in the same matrix output as in your function, but it keeps the connection to your parameters `log_sigma` and `atanh_rho`.

Here is an output before and after the step with the changed `make_covariance_matrix`. As you can see, now you can optimize your parameters and the values do change:

```
Before:
mu: tensor([ 0.1191,  0.7215]), mu_hat: tensor([ 0.,  0.])
sigma: tensor([ 1.4222,  1.0949]), sigma_hat: tensor([ 1.,  1.])
rho: tensor([ 0.2558]), rho_hat: tensor([ 0.])

After:
mu: tensor([ 0.1191,  0.7215]), mu_hat: tensor([ 0.0712,  0.7781])
sigma: tensor([ 1.4222,  1.0949]), sigma_hat: tensor([ 1.4410,  1.0807])
rho: tensor([ 0.2558]), rho_hat: tensor([ 0.2235])
```

Hope this helps!