# Converting spinning up policy gradient to pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm trying to learn deep reinforcement learning through OpenAI spinning up. To do this, I want to rewrite some of their code using pytorch instead of tensorflow.
Currently I'm trying to convert the code for basic policy gradient ([link with explanations](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/spinningup/rl_intro3.html)) and this is my code so far:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.nn.functional import log_softmax
from torch.distributions import Categorical
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np
import gym
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box

class Policy(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, sizes, activation=nn.Tanh(), output_activation=None):
        # Build a feedforward neural network.
        super(Policy, self).__init__()
        self.layers=nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(sizes[i],sizes[i+1]) for i in 
        range(len(sizes)-1)])
        self.activation=activation
        self.output_activation=output_activation
        self.returns=[] # for R(tau) weighting in policy gradient
        self.rewards=[] # list for rewards accrued throughout ep
        self.logits=[]  # for measuring episode logits

    def forward(self,x):

        for layer in self.layers[:-1]:
            x=self.activation(layer(x))

        x=self.layers[-1](x)
        if not self.output_activation==None:
            x=self.output_activation(self.layers[-1](x))
        return x

# make action selection op (outputs int actions, sampled from policy)
def select_action(logits):
    return Categorical(logits=logits).sample()

# make loss function whose gradient, for the right data, is policy gradient
def loss(action_logits,tau_rets):
    return torch.sum(torch.dot(log_softmax(action_logits),tau_rets))

def train(env_name='CartPole-v0', hidden_sizes=[32], lr=1e-2, 
      epochs=50, batch_size=5000, render=False):

# make environment, check spaces, get obs / act dims
env = gym.make(env_name)
assert isinstance(env.observation_space, Box), \
    "This example only works for envs with continuous state spaces."
assert isinstance(env.action_space, Discrete), \
    "This example only works for envs with discrete action spaces."

obs_dim = env.observation_space.shape[0]
n_acts = env.action_space.n

# make core of policy network
policy = Policy(sizes=[obs_dim]+hidden_sizes+[n_acts])

# make train op
train_op = optim.Adam(policy.parameters(), lr=lr)

# for training policy
def train_one_epoch():
    # make some empty lists for logging.
    batch_returns = []         # for measuring episode returns
    batch_lens = []            # for measuring episode lengths

    # reset episode-specific variables
    obs = torch.from_numpy(env.reset()).type(torch.FloatTensor)       # first obs comes from starting distribution
    done = False                                                      # signal from environment that episode is over
    num_obs=0                                                         # to measure the number of observations

    # render first episode of each epoch
    finished_rendering_this_epoch = False

    # collect experience by acting in the environment with current policy
    while True:
        # rendering
        if (not finished_rendering_this_epoch) and render:
            env.render()

        # act in the environment
        act_logit=policy.forward(obs)
        act = select_action(act_logit)
        tmp, reward, done, _ = env.step(act.numpy())
        obs=torch.from_numpy(tmp).type(torch.FloatTensor)
        num_obs+=1

        # save logit, reward
        policy.rewards.append(reward)
        policy.logits.append(act_logit[act].item())

        if done:
            # if episode is over, record info about episode
            ep_ret, ep_len = sum(policy.rewards), len(policy.rewards)
            batch_returns.append(ep_ret)
            batch_lens.append(ep_len)

            # the weight for each logprob(a|s) is R(tau)
            policy.returns+= [ep_ret] * ep_len

            # reset episode-specific variables
            tmp, done, policy.rewards = env.reset(), False, []
            obs=torch.from_numpy(tmp).type(torch.FloatTensor)

            # won't render again this epoch
            finished_rendering_this_epoch = True

            # end experience loop if we have enough of it
            if num_obs > batch_size:
                break

    # take a single policy gradient update step
    print (len(policy.returns),len(policy.rewards),len(policy.logits))
    batch_loss = loss(torch.tensor(policy.logits),torch.tensor(policy.returns))
    batch_loss.backward()
    return batch_loss, batch_returns, batch_lens

# training loop
for i in range(epochs):
    batch_loss, batch_rets, batch_lens = train_one_epoch()
    print('epoch: %3d \t loss: %.3f \t return: %.3f \t ep_len: %.3f'%
            (i, batch_loss, np.mean(batch_rets), np.mean(batch_lens)))
```

When I run train(), I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-163-2da0ffaf5447> in <module>()
----> 1 train()

<ipython-input-162-560e772be08b> in train(env_name, hidden_sizes, lr, epochs, 
batch_size, render)
     114     # training loop
     115     for i in range(epochs):
 --> 116         batch_loss, batch_rets, batch_lens = train_one_epoch()
     117         print('epoch: %3d \t loss: %.3f \t return: %.3f \t ep_len: %.3f'%
     118                 (i, batch_loss, np.mean(batch_rets), np.mean(batch_lens)))

<ipython-input-162-560e772be08b> in train_one_epoch()
     109         print (len(policy.returns),len(policy.rewards),len(policy.logits))
     110         batch_loss = loss(torch.tensor(policy.logits),torch.tensor(policy.returns))
 --> 111         batch_loss.backward()
     112         return batch_loss, batch_returns, batch_lens
     113 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, 
retain_graph, create_graph)
     91                 products. Defaults to ``False``.
     92         """
---> 93         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
     94 
     95     def register_hook(self, hook):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables)
     88     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
     89         tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph,
---> 90         allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
     91 
     92 

RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

I don't understand why this happens since my code is similar to other rl pytorch code such as [this](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/reinforcement_learning/reinforce.py).

Comment: Regarding this line `loss(torch.tensor(policy.logits),torch.tensor(policy.returns))` don't create tensors like this. You are loosing the graph connection! Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53503234/pytorch-parameters-not-changing/53519781#53519781

Comment: For some reason torch.cat didn't work, however torch.stack(...).squeeze() did work.